# Delayed execution of external tasks in Camunda.Worker

Tags: .net, backgroundworker, camunda

I am using Camunda.Worker in my .NET application to create some topic handlers that will complete the service tasks in my Camunda process. Recently (not always) it takes a long time to handle these tasks. I see the logs of my backend and I see it sends requests (fetchAndLock) for some time before it actually executes it. It may take like 5 minutes which is obviously not viable. I don't know if I need further configuration of my handlers. If anyone can provide some additional information I would appreciate it.

*{"version":"7.19.0"}*

Following, I am adding an example of my handler.

Thank you in advance!

```
[![\[HandlerTopics("CreateOrder")\]

public class CreateOrderHandler : IExternalTaskHandler {

public CreateOrderHandler(ILogger<CreateOrderHandler> logger, IFileManager file,
    ICamundaProvider camundaProvider,
    IOrderSubmissionService orderSubmissionService)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _file = file;
    _orderSubmissionService = orderSubmissionService;
    _camundaProvider = camundaProvider;
            }

public async Task<IExecutionResult> HandleAsync(ExternalTask externalTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        string businessKey = externalTask.BusinessKey;

        OrderSubmission orderSubmission = await _orderSubmissionService
            .GetCOrderSubmissionByBusinessKey(businessKey, cancellationToken);

        if (orderSubmission == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        _logger.LogWarning($"businessKey: {businessKey}");

        GeneralResponse<FileDto> response = await _file.GeneratePdf(businessKey, "created_order", cancellationToken);

        var updateResult = await _orderSubmissionService.UpdateOrderSubmissionTaskName(orderSubmission, "Ανάθεση");

        return await _camundaProvider.CreateOrderProtocol(response.Result.FileName);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"error occurred!! error message: {ex.Message}");

        return new BpmnErrorResult("CreateOrderFailure", "Error occurred while creatingorder.");
    }
}  }
```

[image: service task in camunda modeler]